# Discord.JS Reaction Pages | MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

[DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKlng.png) **This is just a testing set.**

Off-topic: If someone wants to make [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x4pv.png) a lot cleaner, I would be grateful.

Topic:
Trying to get pages set up for my Market Command. DB Above.
Right now, I'm using a **FOR loop** to run through the [first 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNxsx.png).
I haven't done anything with Discord.JS reaction messages or pages in general.
Right now, I'm completely oblivious to what I should be trying to do.
Full Listing command in "[first 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNxsx.png)" link.
**If anymore images or another code block is needed, do let me know. I'm willing to spend time on this.**

```js
switch(args[1]) {
    case 'common':
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM market WHERE rarity = 'common'`, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                if ((i+1) <= 10) {
                    Listing.addField(rows[i].username, `**[${rows[i].sellID}]**: **${rows[i].bun}**: ${rows[i].price}`);
                }
            }
            message.channel.send(listing);
        });
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a Reaction catcher but if it's a simple command you can use handlers tooo. Like

```js
let YourEmbed = //The embed
message.channel.send(YourEmbed).then(msg => {
    message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] }).then( emojis => {
        const reaction = emojis.first();
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '➡️') {
            let NewEmbed = //The previous embed but with changed data
            msg.edit(NewEmbed);
        }
    });
});
```

You don't need to fetch all of the items. You can fetch 10 each time. Like

```js
con.query(`SELECT * FROM market WHERE rarity = 'common' LIMIT 10`, (err, rows) => {
    //the rest
```

Next time you can do

```js
con.query(`SELECT * FROM market WHERE rarity = 'common' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`, (err, rows) => {
    //The rest
```

You should put it in a function to make it easier to access. Like:

```js
getRows = (rarity, limit, min) => {
    if(!min){min = 0}
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM market WHERE rarity = ${rarity} LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${min}`, (err, rows) => {
    if(!err){
        return(rows);
    }
}
```

But after all that **I suggest you use a reaction cacher**

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the answer. I would like a little help though. I don't understand how to incorporate that into my current [code](https://i.imgur.com/ouSG1gb.png). I think I understand how to use the offset, but I would like to know; how I could put the reaction cacher into my code, because I don't see how it would work currently, if I just put it in. I may be overlooking it or just out right not understand fully. Again, thanks for the answer, I'll try to get this working.

Comment: @Lexy I suggest adding a separate function for this. Better if you put the function in another file and import it. Thus it'll make it look cleaner. eg In `query.js` you can put the query option. Then call it from `leaderboard.js` Where you can put the function to send the embed and editing it. Finally import it in your main page and put the function inside the `switch..case` you're using. **BTW please note in your code you're using `RichEmbed` which is deprecated and replaced with `MessageEmbed`**